# SQL Query JOIN table through ActiveRecord relations

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Using ActiveRecord relations I have a domain set up through which I am not able to figure out the right query to retrieve the desired information. This may not be the ideal model, but for my project I am required to use a join model that holds information about the relationship.

I want to filter the join table and only return the vehicles that have the status of dealership_vehicles.is_lot_ready = 'f', or 't'. Either way, the closest thing I came up with was a query

```
SELECT *
FROM vehicles
INNER JOIN dealership_vehicles ON vehicles.dealership_vehicle_id = dealership_vehicles.id
WHERE dealership_vehicles.is_lot_ready = false;
```

At first I thought it worked, but upon investigating the data, it was bringing back way too many results, and when the query was changed to 'f' it did not bring any data back.

I cant figure out why, any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
class Dealership < ApplicationRecord
has_many :dealership_vehicles
has_many :vehicles, :through => :dealership_vehicles

class Vehicle < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :dealership_vehicle
has_one :dealership, :through => :dealership_vehicle

class DealershipVehicle < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :dealership
has_many :vehicles
```

And the following data in the tables:

```
vehicles
 id |  make  |  model  | year | dealership_vehicle_id |         created_at         |         updated_at
  1 | BMW    | M3      | 2016 |                     1 | 2018-01-20 16:59:13.196586 | 2018-01-20 16:59:13.196586
  2 | Toyota | Corolla | 2016 |                     2 | 2018-01-20 16:59:13.1998   | 2018-01-20 16:59:13.1998

dealerships
   id | name  |    city     |         created_at         |         updated_at
    1 | Ereve | Lith Harbor | 2018-01-20 16:59:13.067827 | 2018-01-20 16:59:13.067827
    2 | Rien  | Ellinia     | 2018-01-20 16:59:13.070359 | 2018-01-20 16:59:13.070359

dealership_vehicles
 id | dealership_id | is_lot_ready | buyer  | price |         created_at         |         updated_at         | permission
 28 |             4 | f            | Randy  | 30099 | 2018-01-20 16:59:13.183475 | 2018-01-20 16:59:13.183475 |
 27 |             3 | t            | Philip | 30099 | 2018-01-20 16:59:13.180412 | 2018-01-20 16:59:13.180412 |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks to me like you are just missing the single quotes around the `'t'` or `'f'` as it appears you are working with literal strings.

For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM vehicles
INNER JOIN dealership_vehicles ON vehicles.dealership_vehicle_id = dealership_vehicles.id
WHERE dealership_vehicles.is_lot_ready = 'f';
```

Also, if your table only contains the data in your example, you will not be able to find any results because there are no correlating `ID`'s.

See what I mean here, they do not match so you are not able to `JOIN`:

[image]

Comment: unfortunately running that query, returned zero rows, where I was expecting to get back one row, as only one vehicle has its status set to false. Changing the flag to true, most of the records with the correct flag

Comment: The data in your table example would not return any results because the `ID` in `dealership_vehicles` is 27 and 28, which has no correlating rows to `vehicles.dealership_vehicle_id` (these are 1 and 2). If `vehicles.dealership_vehicle_id` was 27 or 28, you would have your 't' or 'f' results respectively

Comment: As soon as you mentioned that i went and checked my data. I was populating the database incorrectly. the vehicles table dealership_vehicle_id only went up to  6. Thanks for quick reply!!

Answer (score 0):

Vehicle.joins(:dealership_vehicle).where(dealership_vehicles: {is_lot_ready: "f"})

Comment: How could I use a placeholder in the is_lot_ready: '?', I am trying to make it work to respond to a passed in variable